# How to solve 'fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory' during PETSc compilation in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, petsc

I am trying to install PETSc on Ubuntu running within the windows subsystem for windows, but the steps detailed [on the official webpage](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html) lead to a compilation error.

First I cloned the PETSc repo and ran the configure command: `./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-openmpi --download-fblaslapack`, which worked. (I already had OpenMPI installed before, but the configure command didn't work without the `--download-openmpi` switch.) Then I executed the make command output by the ./configure code (`make PETSC_DIR=/mnt/c/Stuff/Petsc/petsc PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug all`) and got this error:

```
In file included from /mnt/c/Stuff/Petsc/petsc/src/mat/order/qmdmrg.c:4:0:
/mnt/c/Stuff/Petsc/petsc/include/petscsys.h:134:12: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <mpi.h>
            ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmakefile:153: recipe for target 'arch-linux2-c-debug/obj/mat/order/qmdmrg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch-linux2-c-debug/obj/mat/order/qmdmrg.o] Error 1
```

(The full make output is [here](https://pastebin.com/NPzEuPEu), the error above was only a small part.) Apparently the PETSc make routine can't find MPI, but I have it installed: Running `which mpicc` gives the expected `/usr/bin/mpicc`. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple: I just ran `make all test`. Unlike the suggested command that worked.